# Is there a way to display units in short label?

Tags: units

For example, for`QuantityUnit[Quantity[1, "Meters"]]`, is there a way to display the results as"m" instead of "Meters"?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
QuantityForm[QuantityUnit[Quantity[1, "Meters"]], "Abbreviation"]
(* m *)
```