# Convert units to String

Tags: formatting, units

Is there a way to convert compound units to string?
For example, I have `"Newtons"/"Meters"^2`, how to I convert it to "N/m^2"?
I know If I do the following

```
QuantityForm[QuantityUnit[Quantity[1, "Newtons"/ "Meters"^2]], "Abbreviation"]
```

It will give me "N"/("m")^2, but not "N/m^2".

p.s. The reason I want to do this is that I am writing a function that will copy quantities to excel. After copying units are not displaying correctly

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is there a way to display units in short label?](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/60248/is-there-a-way-to-display-units-in-short-label)

Comment: @eldo Haha, I asked that quation. No, its not the same. Displaying units in short label does not return a units in String.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
stringUnits =  Module[{qf = QuantityForm[QuantityUnit[#], "Abbreviation"], boxes},
  boxes = Cases[ToBoxes[qf], StyleBox[RowBox[{x___}], sty_] :> x];
  StringJoin[ boxes /. x_String :> ToExpression[x] /. Null -> " "  /. 
       SuperscriptBox[a_, b_] :> StringJoin[ToString@a, "^", ToString@b]]] &;

stringUnits @ Quantity["Newton/Meters^2"]
(* "N / m^2" *)
Head[%]
(* String *)

stringUnits @ Quantity[1.84, ("Meters*Pascals/Farads^2")]
(* "m Pa / F^2" *)
Head[%]
(* String *)
```

Works in Version 10 and 9.

Comment: StringQ[%] gives False?

Comment: @kguler (1) This question is a duplicate of http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/60248/is-there-a-way-to-display-units-in-short-label which you answered one hour ago and (2) it doesn't export to Excel. (3) Let me, therefore, post my own deficient answer :)

Comment: @kguler I am very sorry. Thanks for your effort ! ++1

Comment: @eldo, i too thought this was an almost-duplicate and would be really easy till i saw Yituo's edit:)

Comment: I'm not so sure this question is worth the effort that has gone into solving it. :)

Comment: @RunnyKline, i agree -- i think i am done with this one.

Comment: Thanks@kguler! This solves my problem in a general way. Thank you for your help and effort!

Answer (score 11):

The following works for **V10**. First we define some abbreviation rules:

```
rule = {"Newtons" :> N, "Meters" :> m, "Pascals" :> Pa, "Farads" :> F}; (* add more rules here *)
```

Then:

```
unit = TextString[QuantityUnit[Quantity[1, "Newtons/Meters^2"]] /. rule]
```

> ```
> "N/m^2"
> ```

```
StringQ[unit]
```

> True

```
TextString[QuantityUnit[Quantity[1, "Meters*Pascals/Farads^2"]] /. rule]
```

> ```
> "(m*Pa)/F^2"
> ```

Comment: +1 however note that if e.g. `m` has a value this will fail.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard. Thanks for pointing that out. I'll have to think about that.

Comment: Thanks, this will work for specific cases.I guess it will work for my purpose for now, but may need to give it more thougths when a general solution is needed

Answer (score 4):

I recently published a [`ResourceFunction`](https://resources.wolframcloud.com/FunctionRepository/resources/QuantityString/) for this:

```
ResourceFunction["QuantityString"][Quantity[1, "Newtons"/ "Meters"^2]]
```

> 1 N/m^2